# How to make cherry picking react component library like lodash & date/fns

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, package, publish

I have made one small library which includes 20-25 different components & made an npm package of it.

my react project, where I want to use these components, has many pages[routes] used lazy-loading so each page has its own bundle.

but when I write the statement on my home page[App.js].

```
    import { MyModal } from 'my-react-lib';
```

each and every component is loaded into home page bundle. so my initial loading performance is worst. [2Mb initial bundle size]

I have read the concept of tree shaking and event tried to implement in webpack & even with rollup but they only make bundle.js but not as per mine requirement.

I am willing to achieve cherry-picking like import-export. same as date-fns & lodash does.

```
      import format from 'date-fns/format';
      import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
```

how to achieve this?

```
   import MyModal from 'my-react-lib/MyModal';
   import OtherComponent from 'my-react-lib/OtherComponent';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rollup allows you to **split your library into several independent chunks**. You have to provide an object, mapping names to entry points, to the **input** property of the rollup configuration. It looks like this:

```js
input: {
    index: 'src/index.js',
    theme: 'src/Theme',
    badge: 'src/components/Badge',
    contentCard: 'src/components/ContentCard',
    card: 'src/elements/Card',
    icon: 'src/elements/Icon',
    ...
```

`src/index.js` looks like this:

```js
export { default as Theme } from './Theme'
export { default as Badge } from './components/Badge'
...
```

Have a look at rollup’s documentation: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#input

The **output** is set to a directory:

```js
output: [
  {
    dir: 'dist/es',
    format: 'es',
  },
],
```

Then you declare the entry point in your package.json as follows:

```
"module": "dist/es/index.js",
```

The modules of your library can then be imported:

```js
import { Theme, Badge } from 'your-component-library'
```

Comment: @NikhilPatil Have a look here: https://gitlab.com/liquid-design/liquid-design-react

Comment: Can I ask help on my question. Seems related to yours but this is just on the same app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76540814/react-and-vite-why-is-still-loading-other-component-not-imported

Answer (score 1):

You may need to package them separately.

For example the [Material-UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui), there are many parts of it. When we use it in the normal way

```sh
npm install @material-ui/core
```

If you look at their [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages), you would find out that there are multiple packages, each with it's own `package.json` file

For example the **@material-ui/core** [pacakge.json](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/package.json)

```
{
  "name": "@material-ui/core",
  "version": "4.9.7",
  "private": false,
  "author": "Material-UI Team",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.6",
    "@material-ui/system": "^4.9.6",
    "@material-ui/types": "^5.0.0",
    "@material-ui/utils": "^4.9.6",
```

Which means that they are actually separate and have dependencies with each other.

Well, that's the scope.

Comment: If we do that each component size is much bigger, because each and every component will have react & react dom as it's dependency.

Comment: @NikhilPatil Well, case by case in my opinion. At least this is a real-world solution, maybe with some certain circumstances.

Comment: @NikhilPatil Cool, post as an answer if you have made it.

Comment: I found the final solution, borisdiakur link is the answer.

https://gitlab.com/liquid-design/liquid-design-react