# React and Vite - Why is still loading other component not imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, vite

I have made some configs on `tsconfig.paths.json` and this is how I structure files below.

My problem is with the importing, Is it good to import just like this?

`import { Products } from '@components'`.

My problem is because I notice it loads all components even though I didn't import all.
For example if I go to `/sample-page/`, it loads `People`, `Food`, `Events`.

Would it better if I do `import Products from '@components/Products'`, so it won't load other components such as People, Food, Events?

**folder structure**

```
- src
   - Components
      - Products
      - People
      - Food
      - Events
      - index.ts
```

**index.ts**

```
import Products from './Products';
import People from './People';
import Food from './Food';
import Events from './Events';

export {
   Products,
   People,
   Food,
   Events
}
```

**tsconfig.paths.json**

```
{
   "@components/*": ["src/Components/*"],
}
```

**Sample Page(/sample-page)**

```
import { Products } from '@components'

const SamplePage = () => {
   return(
      <>
         <Products />
      </>
   )
}

export default SamplePage
```

Comment: Do you see this in dev mode or in production?

Comment: @FelixKling. In both dev and prod

Comment: Even in prod? It makes sense in dev since the browser loads the modules directly and it cannot know what is or isn't used, so everything is loaded. I'd expect tree-shaking to work as expected in prod though.

Comment: @FelixKling. Yes it still loads unecessary files in prod